# Metamask recovered from seed, not showing previous transactions

Tags: metamask

I want to use my Metamask wallet on a different pc so I installed the chrome plugin and entered the words seed. The balance shown seems to be correct, but I cannot find a history of my previous transactions... Anyway to show this in the new metamask wallet?

Comment: This may correspond to this issue : https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-plugin/issues/505

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it will look up previous transactions in the chain. Afacit the only way to do that is by looping over the blocks and I can't see any code that does that.

edit: my comment is substantiated by the issue that Nicolas linked above: https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-plugin/issues/505 MetaMask does not implement this functionality (although other wallets might).

Comment: Online tx explorers displays all the history (see random address example: https://etherscan.io/address/0x645db031d6ac9f3a69566123bf26878a4990ebef )

Answer (score 0):

etherscan.io is a very useful tool, you can find every tx history there.